# Get all Beans with a qualifier

Tags: cdi, weld, weld-se

I am looking to get all Beans with a Qualifier. My current approach is to get all registered Beans and look for the Qualifier annotation. But since the Beans are proxy objects this is not possible.

I am using Weld SE 2.2

Comment: One question for clarification : You would like to receive all implementations of an interface that are annotated with a particular qualifier? Or do you would like to have all beans (that are not necessarily implement a common interface) that are annotated with a particular qualifier?